# Italics work everywhere except in less(1)

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, tmux, less

I followed (and modified) [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/24g8r8/italics_in_terminal_vim_and_tmux/) to get italics working in Terminal.app and in tmux(1).

### Italics work

The command

```
echo -e "\e[3mfoo\e[23m"
```

outputs *foo* (with italics) in both a regular terminal session and a tmux session.

Also in both, the command sequence

```
vim README.md
i*foo*<Esc>
```

edits a file `README.md` and shows the text `*foo*` in italics.

### Except in less

In tmux, less(1) shows all "emphasized" lines (such as the prompt) using italics.

Outside of tmux, no cigar. less will use the "normal" reverse-highlight to show the emphasized lines.

### Question

Why is the observed behavior of less different between a regular session and tmux, but other programs are not?

How can I make less behave more uniformly?

### Relevant information

- `TERM`: either `xterm-256color` or `tmux-256color`
- `xterm-256color` and `tmux-256color` definitions:

```
# A xterm-256color based TERMINFO that adds the escape sequences for italic.
#
# Install:
#
#   tic xterm-256color.terminfo
#
# Usage:
#
#   export TERM=xterm-256color
#
xterm-256color|xterm with 256 colors and italic,
        sitm=\E[3m, ritm=\E[23m,
        use=xterm-256color,
```

```
# A tmux-256color based TERMINFO that adds the escape sequences for italic.
#
# Install:
#
#   tic tmux-256color.terminfo
#
# Usage:
#
#   export TERM=tmux-256color
#
tmux-256color|tmux with 256 colors and italic,
        sitm=\E[3m, ritm=\E[23m,
        use=screen-256color,
```

- `sitm` and `ritm` sequences in both `TERM`s:

  - `sitm=\E[3m`
  - `ritm=\E[23m`
- vimscript for italics:

```
if $TERM =~# '\v(xterm|tmux)-256color' || has('gui_running')
  if has('osx')
    let &t_ZH = "\e[3m"
    let &t_ZR = "\e[23m"
  endif
endif
```

Comment: I wasn't sure if this was on topic for [unix.se], so I came here instead. If it's off-topic here, apologies. Please let me know where a better place to ask is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect less is using smso, not sitm. You have derived tmux-256color from screen-256color which has smso set to SGR 3:

```
$ infocmp screen-256color|grep smso
    smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smso=\E[3m, smul=\E[4m, tbc=\E[3g,
```

This means you will get italics inside tmux. The reason smso is SGR 3 in screen-256color is that screen does not support italics and uses SGR 3 for inverse instead (I think this might have changed now but I'm not sure).

xterm-256color however has smso set to SGR 7:

```
$ infocmp xterm-256color|grep smso
    smir=\E[4h, smkx=\E[?1h\E=, smm=\E[?1034h, smso=\E[7m,
```

This means you will get standout (inverse) outside tmux.

So to fix this, modify your terminfo entries to set smso consistently to whatever you prefer (italics or inverse) for both xterm-256color and tmux-256color.

I assume you already have this since you have italics working in tmux, but make sure you have default-terminal set to tmux-256color in .tmux.conf or tmux will emulate screen and send smso rather than sitm for italics.

Comment: I do have the default-terminal set, but that’s a good eye to spot that. Thanks, I’ll give it a try

Comment: You might want to just use the full tmux-256color from upstream ncurses which also has stuff like modified cursor keys (don't forget -x to tic): https://gist.githubusercontent.com/nicm/6b10ed9ad64e4cc1769644002392be1c/raw/00c13fb339b888e6d36f417667b523a5a948fc24/tmux-256color

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-r` (`--raw-control-chars`) or `-R` (`--RAW-CONTROL-CHARS`) option of `less` to make it interpret special characters instead of escaping them. `-R` should only interpret `\E[...m` sequences, while `-r` interprets everything.

To enable the option always, set the env variable `$LESS` to `-R`.

Comment: Ack, I forgot to include my `LESS`. I’ll update when i get back to my laptop, but I believe it is RWi or similar